# How do use SQL scripts in R

Tags: sql, r

I need to write a SQL query

Here are my tables

```
x <- read.csv("C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/Set 1-1.csv",sep=",",dec=".")
y <- read.csv("C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/Set 1-2 - Copy.csv",sep=",",dec=".")
y$score <- 1
```

I tried joining it

```
library("sqldf")
select clientid,emailmessageid,null cnttrn,idatediff,null score from x 
union all select clientid,emailmessageid,cnttrn,idatediff,score from y
```

But I get the following errors:

> select clientid,emailmessageid,null cnttrn,idatediff,null score from x
>
> Error: unexpected symbol in "select clientid"
>
> union all select
>   clientid,emailmessageid,cnttrn,idatediff,score from y
>
> Error:
>   unexpected symbol in "union all"

Please help to correct it. Thank you.

dput(x)

```
ClientID    EmailMessageId  MinDate MaxDate IdSlip  WwsCreatedDate  ProductArticle  ProductGroupName    MainProductGroupName    CategoryGroupName   QtytItems   SumAmount   iDateDiff
3E34C0C9FC05975CC0F01D7A3DEE73D022538FA04B17A0316178E090C04F84A8    894DB62F7B7A6ED2    31.08.2016  31.08.2016  4A19280A1164CF3F4A701EF9AE97A1F1084B611000B94C02    24.09.2015  item1   item2   item3   item4   1   580.0   -342
3E34C0C9FC05975CC0F01D7A3DEE73D022538FA04B17A0316178E090C04F84A8    894DB62F7B7A6ED2    31.08.2016  31.08.2016  4A19280A1164CF3F4A701EF9AE97A1F1084B611000B94C02    24.09.2015  item1   item2   item3   item4   1   3190.0  -342
```

dput(y)

```
ClientID    EmailMessageId  CntTrn  iDateDiff   score
86139F31664463A8B7592B6887B731A9FC2C3489BB1756A5BF334CFDEA4EF604    9EDCC1391C208BA0    1   4   1
BD483D69913E3EBFE5FBA87A1FFAB7DCD061055FFB4342C2F27AC01F36833254    EF72D53990BC4805    1   5   1
0B3B2F06C3033B3AFD83BA59B405BCC79BC69801FD3B69931F117B8D754A80EB    9EDCC1391C208BA0    1   3   1
```

Comment: You need to use the `sqldf()` to wrap your query. Something like `sqldf("select * from x")`

Comment: i saw it in help, but same error :'(

Comment: Share some data using the output from `dput(head(x))` and `dput(head(y))` to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This runs without errors for me. The only difference is that the query is formatted. Is the result correct?

```
library(sqldf)

y <- read.table(text = "ClientID    EmailMessageId  CntTrn  iDateDiff   score
86139F31664463A8B7592B6887B731A9FC2C3489BB1756A5BF334CFDEA4EF604    9EDCC1391C208BA0    1   4   1
BD483D69913E3EBFE5FBA87A1FFAB7DCD061055FFB4342C2F27AC01F36833254    EF72D53990BC4805    1   5   1
0B3B2F06C3033B3AFD83BA59B405BCC79BC69801FD3B69931F117B8D754A80EB    9EDCC1391C208BA0    1   3   1", header = TRUE)

x <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "ClientID    EmailMessageId  MinDate MaxDate IdSlip  WwsCreatedDate  ProductArticle  ProductGroupName    MainProductGroupName    CategoryGroupName   QtytItems   SumAmount   iDateDiff
3E34C0C9FC05975CC0F01D7A3DEE73D022538FA04B17A0316178E090C04F84A8    894DB62F7B7A6ED2    31.08.2016  31.08.2016  4A19280A1164CF3F4A701EF9AE97A1F1084B611000B94C02    24.09.2015  item1   item2   item3   item4   1   580.0   -342
3E34C0C9FC05975CC0F01D7A3DEE73D022538FA04B17A0316178E090C04F84A8    894DB62F7B7A6ED2    31.08.2016  31.08.2016  4A19280A1164CF3F4A701EF9AE97A1F1084B611000B94C02    24.09.2015  item1   item2   item3   item4   1   3190.0  -342")

sqldf("
SELECT 
  ClientId,
  EmailMessageId,
  null CntTrn,
  iDateDiff,
  null Score 
FROM x 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
      ClientId,
      EmailMessageId,
      CntTrn,
      iDateDiff,
      Score 
FROM y")
```

Comment: Yes it works, but if i want add any columns like ProductGroupName, MainProductGroupName from (x)
i get error 
`
'> mydata=sqldf("
+ SELECT 
+       ClientID,
+       EmailMessageId,
+       null ProductGroupName
+       null CntTrn,
+       iDateDiff,
+       null Score 
+       FROM x 
+       
+       UNION ALL 
+       
+       SELECT 
+       ClientID,
+       EmailMessageId,
+       ProductGroupName 
+       CntTrn,
+       iDateDiff,
+       Score 
+       FROM y")
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  near "null": syntax error`
> 
Please help

Comment: Product Group Name is absent in a dataset, how to add?

Comment: Just add any columns to the SELECT clause as you would with normal SQL. If you want a new column with no data in: `sqldf("SELECT ClientID, EmailMessageId, null ProductGroupName, null CntTrn, iDateDiff, null Score FROM x UNION ALL SELECT ClientID, EmailMessageId, NULL, CntTrn, iDateDiff, Score FROM y")`

Comment: yes you right, but i don't want null ProductGroupName, how to do that in new table productgroupname contain information, now after script done, i see null data in this field, i need full data corresponding with key:)
if i erase "null" i see next error
`> mydata=sqldf("select clientid,emailmessageid,ProductGroupName,MainProductGroupName,null cnttrn,idatediff,null score from x  
+              union all select clientid,emailmessageid,ProductGroupName, MainProductGroupName,cnttrn,idatediff,score from y")
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  no such column: ProductGroupName`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, and I can't tell if you are familiar with SQL or not, but it might be easier for you to try some things yourself. I suspect you will need to JOIN the table containing ProductGroupName with either x or y on a common key like ClientId. If the answer to your original question was sufficient then mark it as correct and if you're still stuck with this problem (and it hasn't already been asked on StackOverflow) then post a new question.